# PDF to flipbook for website

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, document-converter, documentation-viewer

I'm looking for a solution to make a PDF into a flipbook/pageflip like this http://fliphtml5.com/jvnr/uxpk for example.

I think these broadly fall into two categories, hosted services like fliphtml5.com where you upload a PDF to a third party server and you link to them, or ones hosted on your own server and you embed the flipbook within your site (like http://www.turnjs.com, but they seems to only work with images?).

I need it to be responsive and work on PC/MAC desptops, iOS and Andriod phone/tablets. No Flash.

For use on an NGO website.

Paid (not too expensive) or free.

Has to have the corner of the page rolling up effect (client says!)

fliphtml5.com looks good but $15 p/m may be a bit too much

This looks good https://flipbookplugin.com - has anyone any experience of it?

Site is not Wordpress BTW

Thanks!

Comment: I would strongly discourage this corner page rolling effect. Users want fast/responsive page navigation, not "cool" effects. No other major ebook/pdf readers do this effect. In fact, it just gets in the way of page navigation, and makes things slower IMHO. "but they seems to only work with images?" The page curl effect, as far as I know, is always done by transforming a static image.

Comment: @ryan I agree, but the client is insisting on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ones that is hosted on your own server and you embed the flipbook within your site, you can use [dFlip PDF FlipBook jQuery Plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/dflip-flipbook-jquery-plugin/15834127).

It is flash free. Costs only $29 for regular license with 6 months customer support. You can create 3D or 2D flipbooks easily with this plugin. Additionally it has awesome page rolling effect.

Comment: Thanks, I actually looked at that myself but did not buy. Good to see someone recommends it. The client has decided to drop this requirement for now... but I'll give that a try if they decide to use it again..

Answer (score 1):

The company I work for has this (paid) SDK.
https://www.pdftron.com/

See this online demo
https://www.pdftron.com/samples/web/samples/advanced/flipbook/

Source code
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/js/flipbook

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/samples/advanced#flipbook

Comment: Thank you for that info. I actually came across this myself but the cost out me off "PDFTron license pricing starts at US $4000 per year" - unfortunately my clients don't have pockets that deep, or that's what they tell me anyway!